# MySQL SELECT values with more than three words

Tags: mysql, sql, select, where-clause, sql-like

I currently have the following code

```
select *
FROM list
WHERE name LIKE '___'
ORDER BY name;
```

I am trying to get it so that it only shows names with three or more words.
It only displays names with three characters
I cannot seem to work out the correct syntax for this.

Any help is appreciated
Thankyou

Comment: You mean three letters or words?

Comment: Three words @OvaisKhatri

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you assume that there are no double spaces, you can do:

```
WHERE name like '% % %'
```

To get names with three or more words.

If you can have double spaces (or other punctuation), then you are likely to want a regular expression.  Something like:

```
WHERE name REGEXP '^[^ ]+[ ]+[^ ]+.*$'
```

Comment: I suspect that there's an even more elegant solution along these lines - but I'm hopelessly bad at regex

Comment: `WHERE name like '% % % %'` would only get names with 4 or more words.

Comment: to change it to four or more words would it be as follows WHERE title REGEXP '^[^ ]+[ ]+[^ ]+[ ]+[^ ]+[ ]+[^ ].*$'

Answer (score 1):

you can count number of words and then select those who are equal or greater then 3 words.

```
    SELECT * FROM list
    HAVING LENGTH(name) - LENGTH(REPLACE(name, ' ', ''))+1 >= 3
    ORDER BY name
```

[**DEMO HERE**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ef6c7/3)

*Even if you have multi spaces it will not affect here check [this](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/fa940/1)

Answer (score 0):

I do believe what you are after is

```
SELECT *
FROM list
WHERE name LIKE '% % %'
ORDER BY name;
```